# ¿como guardar con un <select> en la base de datos?

Tags: php

Necesito que cuando selecionen una opcion y den click en el boton guardar me guarde y mi base de datos pero no como programar la parte php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba Select</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">Peter </option>
          <option value="2">Lois </option>
          <option value="3">Joseph </option>
          <option value="4">Glenn</option>
         </select>

    <input style="border-radius: 8px" type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar">

    </center>   
</body>
</html>


<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin123','database');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        </tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Probaste algo? porque no es solo programar la parte de php, hay que crear una conexion, y llenar la tabla. Si no lo hiciste, averigua como se hace eso, si no la pregunta es un poco vaga.

Comment: si claro eso ya lo hize pero no funciona

Comment: que quiere decir no funciona? que error recibis? ahi solo estas haciendo un select, donde estas guardando los datos?

Comment: no guarda en la base de datos

Comment: No hay ninguna operación INSERT o UPDATE. No va a guardar nunca.

Comment: De hecho tampoco hay formulario. A no ser (y ya vamos suponiendo) que esté enviando los datos vía Javascript... Y como dicen los demás usuarios, falta toda la implementación de inserción/actualización del registro, etc... Por favor, agrega el código que te pedimos, para saber cómo has intentado guardar en la base de datos tu dato del combo.

Comment: de hecho el código esta mla planteado también desde que haces mysqli_select_db, se supone que si ya usas mysqli eso que haces es obsoleto e incorrecto

Answer (score 2):

Mira tu select tiene como name  `users`

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

Además en tu código php tienes `$q = intval($_GET['q'])` y deberia ser asi

```
$q = intval($_GET['users']);
```

> Tambien tienes que agregar mas cosas de tu código puesto que solo
>   estas listando elementos, en ningun momento veo que guardas.